# How to make a counter based on user response?

Tags: c#, counter, pass-by-reference

I'm trying to make a counter that will increment based on the response of the user. Here's the code I got so far:

```
        string ok = "";
        int z = 0;
        test(ok, z);
        test1(ok, z);
        Console.WriteLine(z);
    }

        static void test(string ok, int z)
        {

            bool estok = false;
            while (!estok)
            {
                ConsoleKeyInfo saisie = Console.ReadKey(true);
                if (saisie.Key == ConsoleKey.A || saisie.Key == ConsoleKey.B)
                {
                    estok = true;
                    if (saisie.Key == ConsoleKey.A)
                    {

                        z++;
                    }

                    if (saisie.Key == ConsoleKey.B)
                    {
                        z--;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    estok = false;
                    Console.WriteLine("Error");
                }
            }


        }
            static void test1(string ok, int z)
            {
                bool estok = false;
                while (!estok)
                {
                    ConsoleKeyInfo saisie = Console.ReadKey(true);
                    if (saisie.Key == ConsoleKey.A || saisie.Key == ConsoleKey.B)
                    {
                        estok = true;
                        if (saisie.Key == ConsoleKey.A)
                        {
                            z++;
                        }

                        if (saisie.Key == ConsoleKey.B)
                        {
                            z--;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        estok = false;
                        Console.WriteLine("Error");
                    }
                }
            }
```

I got 2 functions (`test` and `test1`) that both increment the `int z`. The `Console.WriteLine(z)` will return me 0, in place of the 2 i'm waiting for (when the user has 2 correct answers).

I figured that the increment won't happen since it's in the function and that the `Console.WriteLine(z)` can't reach the `z++`. How can I change that ?

How can I get the result from these?

Comment: "[How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)"

Comment: C# method parameters have value semantics by default. Changes you do in the method to not apply to the object you passed from Main(). The better method here is to return the value z from the methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int` and other primitive types are passed by value by default where as reference types (think instances of a class) are passed by reference; this is what allows changes to the parameter to be persisted after the method returns. The way you are updating the value of the parameter, you'll need to pass `z` by reference.

`static void test(string ok, int z)`
becomes 
`static void test(string ok, ref int z)`

and the call `test(ok, z);` becomes `test(ok, ref z);`

You can learn more about passing values by reference from the [C# Language  Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref)

Answer (score 0):

method parameters for int are of value types and not reference type, as far as I understood from your question, you may need to use out keyword in the method call or return from the method you have.

```
int z1= z;
test(ok, out z1);
int z2=z;
test1(ok, out z2);
```

and the method declaration also will have to be changed to

```
static void test(string ok, out int z)


static void test1(string ok, out int z)
```

OR you can simply put a `Console.WriteLine(z)` in the method test and test1 directly.